# ITMS - 90179 Invalid Code Signing / ITMS - 90209 Invalid Segment Alignment

Tags: ios, flash, app-store, application-loader

ERROR ITMS - 90179 Invalid Code Signing. The Executable 'Payload/UFO.app/UFO' must be signed with a certificate that is contained in the provisioning profile.

ERROR ITMS - 90209 Invalid Segment Alignment. The app binary at 'UFO.app/UFO' does not have a proper segment alignment. Try rebuilding the app with the latest Xcode version.

I've been getting these two errors no matter what I try. I've deleted all my profiles and certificates, remade them and even remade the App ID multiple times and nothing happened and still the same error. I've updated XCode too and still the same errors.

I used a Wildcard App to create my .ipa file in Flash Pro CC selecting the Apple App Store and tried to publish it through application loader.

Is there any solution to these two problems? Thanks.

Comment: Any progress? I am running into the same problem. Did you experience the issue with the latest ios 64 bit requirement SDK update?

Comment: same happens in Flash Builder http://i.imgur.com/gSXYkY7.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a conflict with both dev and prod certificates.
I was finally able to submit following these steps:

(1) go in keychain and delete both certificates (dev & distribution)

(2) go to apple site and download distribution certificate only

(3) install distribution cert only!

(4) export p12 from private key

(5) go to apple and regenerate/download distribution provisioning profile.

From there it worked fine, don't ask why...

Comment: Why step 5? aren't steps 1..4 supposed to be enough?

Comment: I'm just saying what worked for me, no what makes sense to me :)

Comment: heheh thanks anyway :-) I solved it they way I wrote in this thread

Answer (score 1):

Restart the Xcode, it should resolve before trying above suggestions. Its a classic trick which seem to work even today :P

Comment: I've also cleaned up the project several times after restart in addition. And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

my english is not so good but i will try to explain my self the best i can...
y just solve this error that i was also having "ERROR ITMS - 90179 Invalid Code Signing. The Executable 'Payload/UFO.app/UFO' must be signed with a certificate that is contained in the provisioning profile".....
First of all my app is using push notifications so i created a push notification certificate and install it on my Keychain (aps_production), along with my app distribution certificate (ios_production.cer ), and i was exporting my app distribution certificate(ios_production.cer ) using the keychain to export it to the .p12 file....this way i was getting that error...what i did is that i erased everything on my keychain and just install the ios_distribution.cer without the aps_production.cer , this way i fix this issue.....it seems that if you export to the .p21 with others files on your keychain related to your same app. your certificate gets and error...hope this helps you...

Answer (score 0):

I had ITMS-90179 uploading an iPhone App made with Marmalade SDK. Solved it this way:

1.- Deleted all my distribution certificates at Apple dev portal

2.- Created a new Distribution certificate

3.- Deleted all my distribution provisioning profiles

4.- Created a new distribution provisioning profile

5.- Generated a new .ipa using the .mobileprovision from step 4

6.- Attempted to upload this one to App Store, this time it worked.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I was also faced with the "ERROR ITMS - 90179 Invalid Code Signing" issue. What I ended up doing, was:

1. Created a new macOS account with a completely empty Keychain
2. Imported our iOS Distribution Certificate and Private Key
3. Regenerated and downloaded Provisioning Profile from Apple Developer Portal
4. Resigned MyApp.ipa
5. Validated MyResignedApp.ipa using Appl. Loader (see below)
6. Uploaded to iTunes Connect

This worked, which tells me that resigning using my usual account probably messed up some of the certificates in my Keychain!?

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Support/altool --validate-app -f MyResignedApp.ipa -t ios -u my_itunes_connect_account@mac.com
```