# Adobe AIR AppStore upload error: Invalid Code Signing Entitlements... 'get-task-allow' (

Tags: ios, air, adobe, entitlements

I've been trying to upload a version of my game to the AppStore for the past two days.
I keep getting the following errors:

> ERROR ITMS-90164: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. According to the provisioning profile, the bundle contains a key value that is not allowed: 'true' for the key 'get-task-allow' in 'Payload/Game.app/Game'"
>
> ERROR ITMS-90179: "Invalid Code Signing. The executable 'Payload/Game.app/Game' must be signed with the certificate that is contained in the provisioning profile."

Using FlashDevelop, Air 19.0 (since the latest problems in AIR 20.0 - 21.0).

I haven't included the get-task-allow tag in my application.xml, I've doubled checked my certificates, provisioning profiles etc., and even recreated them - but nothing seems to make it work...

Feels like a certificates issue to me, but I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 22):

I had the error ERROR ITMS-90164: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements" with key get-task-allow and I simply did both a Clean and Clean Build Folder, and I was able to upload to the App Store with no problems.  Interestingly enough, I had done a validation on the problematic ipa before and it passed App Store validation, but failed on the actual upload after the file was uploaded.

Comment: I just didn't get it working using xcodebuild from the command line, but it worked after cleaning and rebuilding using Xcode directly, which of course is not really an option when using CI. Very strange...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved with a simple **Product -> Clean.**

Answer (score 1):

In your app descriptor xml try adding the entitlement for get-task-allow.

```
<iPhone>        
<Entitlements><![CDATA[
<key>get-task-allow</key><false/>
]]></Entitlements>
<!--
<Entitlements>
</iPhone>
```

And yes it does sound like you are mixing up certificates and profiles somewhere along the line.

Are you sure you are using an AppStore profile? (i.e. not AdHoc or development).

Answer (score 0):

Yes - I'm using an AppStore profile.

After some trials, I've deleted all certificates, mobile provisions etc. and re-created them. I've followed this advice as well:
[ITMS - 90179 Invalid Code Signing / ITMS - 90209 Invalid Segment Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359988/itms-90179-invalid-code-signing-itms-90209-invalid-segment-alignment)

And it's working now. Apple voodoo...