# Xamarin Forms - iOS Distribution AppStore error

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, app-store, testflight

I want to publish my Xmarin Form - iOS app to TestFlight but when select Distributon to AppStore and enter App ID with specific password then this error appearing and i don't know what's wrong.

Im using VS2019 for window and pair to my Mac mini, XamarinFom 4.5 with Firebase Authentication include in app.

[image]

Comment: Use transporter on Mac instead.

Comment: @Adlorem it doesn't work, the issue still same

Comment: Try to reinstall your certification and provisioning profile in your local machine. Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359988/itms-90179-invalid-code-signing-itms-90209-invalid-segment-alignment) may help.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT tks for your help, i did it

Comment: You can share your solution in the answer which will help more people with same problem:).